# Android intents onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I m facing this weird problem with Intents,only the first activity is launching, if i click the second button, it closes the app.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    //working
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    //not working
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, A.class);
            startActivity(i1);

        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the onClick method, but i m not sure what to write in there.
I have added it in the manifest file..so thats not the issue..

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Search" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"

    android:text="Store" />
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Post the logcat.

Comment: I'll make a bet. Your B.class is not in the manifest.

Comment: I agree to Mighter, Make sure you have declared Activity 'B' in Manifest file.

Comment: i hav added it in the manifest file..

Comment: Ok, then post your Activity B, logcat output and activity_main.xml as well.

Comment: Logcat:
04-17 17:37:21.392: E/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 17:37:21.392: E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wheresmyspot2/com.example.wheresmyspot2.Store}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment


its too long, so i've just copies the starting few lines

Comment: check line no. 7, the error is inflating layout file.

Comment: @BlueLeaf : Don't post code or logcat into comments - just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <!-- Declaration Activity B -->
        <activity android:name="B" >
        </activity>
```

**Edit:** Your error is inflating xml file. Your layout file is having some problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not Declared the activities in the AndroidManifest.xml

Add them like below code for each class you created.

```
 <activity android:name="yourPackage.NewClassyouCreated" >
        </activity>
```